# How to install mongodb erlang driver?

Tags: mongodb, erlang, installation, driver

I would like use mongodb erlang driver however I am not able to clone it through git.
I have downloaded driver zip. Now I don't know how to use it.

I tried to include the driver in the following way but doesn't work :(
-include ("zip extracted path/mongo_protocol.hrl").

Is anything I need to do with that driver unzipped folder.?

Comment: Why you aren't able to clone it with Git?

Comment: If you are using the driver from MongoDB, here is the installation guide https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-erlang#installing

Comment: @Chiron: I am not able to use because my machine's internet access is through proxy server. I am not able to ping/access any outside world machine like (google.com,github.com) :(

Answer (score 0):

Basing on the comment, here is the answer regarding the installation process:

If you are using the driver from MongoDB, here is the installation guide [Installing MongoDB Erlang Driver.](https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-erlang#installing)